# Ubuntu 19.10, 100% GPU usage, overheating

Tags: overheating, gpu

I have a laptop with AMD Ryzen 5 3500U, integrated VEGA GPU. Lately it is always overheating even while doing nothing, CPU usage very low. 
Using radeontop, it turns out that the GPU is running at or near 100% all the time when GNOME is running, even if not doing anything.
I think this other question ([19.10: Constantly overheating Dell XPS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209586/19-10-constantly-overheating-dell-xps)) with an Intel GPU may be the same problem, which would indicate that it isn't AMD-specific, but I can't really find anything else about it via Google. What can I do, and where should I report it?

Edit for extra info:

- Minimal install standard Ubuntu 19.10.
- Tried the oibaf ppa for newer graphics drivers and the problem still existed.
- Doesn't overheat in "recovery mode"
- [radeontop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqNAt.png)

I'd like to know if that similar sounding problem that I linked is the same, but I can't post there because of reputation below 50?. It would be nice to see his intel_gpu_top.

Comment: I think you can better ask this on a ubuntuforums.org/ since you are providing little data, and having 1000s of comments asking you for the output of certain commands seems folly.

Comment: I think it's a fair question for AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 1):

The problem went away on its own after Ubuntu upgraded to linux package 5.3.0-40. If I boot into an older kernel (like 5.3.0-29), it still happens, so it seems there was a problem there for a while, but appears to be fixed.